# mvc default model binder only binds first word of a string?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, string, bind

Why does my action method only bind the first word of a string I pass into it using a query string?

For example, in jquery, I build a queryString from the results of an ajax call:

```
success: return(resultData){
  var queryString = "?ok=true&message=" + resultData.message;
}
```

Then I try to load a view into a dialog by calling a controller and passing the queryString

```
$dialogHandle.load("/Account/RegisterStatus" + queryString, function() { ... });
```

At this point the queryString correctly hold an entire message. However if I break in my controller:

```
public ActionResult RegisterStatus(bool ok, string message)
{
        //break here
}
```

I notice that ok binds correctly but message only contains the first word of the error message passed in.

How can I pass a sentence as one string parameter?
Is there a better way to do this, without query string?

EDIT: hmm now that I think about it does make sense since urls cant have space but then how do I accomplish this... is there a specific word delimiter in the default model binder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about [URL escaping](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm): `escape("It's me!") // result: It%27s%20me%21`

Do that around your `resultData.Message` and it should work better. For debugging purposes, use Fiddler2 or some Web Inspector to see what request is being send. This is really valuable when you are debugging AJAX...

And of course, do the reverse in C#: [HttpUtility.UrDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx)